# Exception while booting debian 8 for powerPC with qemu-system-ppc on Ubuntu 16.04 host

Tags: debian, qemu, powerpc

I was trying to create and boot Debian 8 PowerPC VM under QEMU on Ubuntu 16.04 host using this guide https://gist.github.com/nstarke/c6593da117c459c18c255395211fa311

I used the following commands:

Copy files from iso

```
$ mkdir ~/powerpc-mnt    
$ sudo mount /path/to/iso/debian-8.11.0-powerpc-DVD-1.iso ~/powerpc-mnt    
$ cp ~/powerpc-mnt/install/powerpc/initrd.gz ./    
$ cp ~/powerpc-mnt/install/powerpc/vmlinux ./    
$ sudo umount ~/powerpc-mnt
```

Command to install

```
$ qemu-system-ppc -m 1024 -boot d -hda powerpc32.img -initrd initrd.gz -kernel vmlinux -append  "cdrom-detect/try-usb=true" -device qemu-xhci,id=xhci
-device usb-storage,bus=xhci.0,drive=dvd
-drive file=debian-8.11.0-powerpc-DVD-1.iso,media=cdrom,if=none,id=dvd -no-reboot
```

Extract files from image

```
$ sudo modprobe nbd max_part=16    
$ sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 powerpc32.img    
$ mkdir ~/qemu-mounted    
$ sudo mount /dev/nbd0p2 ~/qemu-mounted    
$ mkdir after-copy    
$ cp ~/qemu-mounted/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-powerpc after-copy/    
$ cp ~/qemu-mounted/vmlinux-3.16.0-6-powerpc after-copy/    
$ sudo umount ~/qemu-mounted    
$ sudo qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
```

Command to boot

```
$ qemu-system-ppc -m 1024 -hda powerpc32.img -initrd after-copy/initrd.img-3.16.0-6-powerpc -kernel after-copy/vmlinux-3.16.0-6-powerpc -append  "root=/dev/sda3" "-nic user,hostfwd=tcp::7777-:22".
```

Installation was successful, but when I tried to boot into installed OS I got an exception (the log is given below). Tried to reinstall, but it didn't help. Can anyone help me to understand what can be wrong? I have no ideas.

```
[   60.212316] input: Mouseemu virtual mouse as /devices/virtual/input/input3    
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Emulate mouse buttons and mouse wheel.    
[  OK  ] Started LSB: keep memory of all UPnP devices that an...ced themselves.    
[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.    
[  OK  ] Started Authenticate and Authorize Users to Run Privileged Tasks.    
Debian GNU/Linux 8 natasha-VirtualBox ttyPZ0    
[   70.801444] e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX    
[   73.797676] irq 17: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)    
[   73.799351] CPU: 0 PID: 395 Comm: ModemManager Not tainted 3.16.0-6-powerpc #1 Debian 3.16.56-1+deb8u1    
[   73.801243] Call Trace:    
[   73.802343] [efff5ed0] [c000966c] show_stack+0xf8/0x1b0 (unreliable)    
[   73.804046] [efff5f20] [c008ef3c] __report_bad_irq.isra.7+0x40/0xec    
[   73.805241] [efff5f40] [c008f304] note_interrupt+0x29c/0x2f4    
[   73.806366] [efff5f70] [c008cddc] handle_irq_event_percpu+0xe8/0x1dc    
[   73.808954] [efff5fb0] [c008cf10] handle_irq_event+0x40/0x60    
[   73.809972] [efff5fc0] [c008f908] handle_level_irq+0x9c/0x14c    
[   73.810552] [efff5fd0] [c008c3a0] generic_handle_irq+0x48/0x68    
[   73.811132] [efff5fe0] [c0006e08] __do_irq+0x44/0xf4    
[   73.811625] [efff5ff0] [c000f2fc] call_do_irq+0x24/0x3c    
[   73.812133] [eda15be0] [c0006f28] do_IRQ+0x70/0xc0    
[   73.812696] [eda15c00] [c000c0ec] timer_interrupt+0x34/0x64    
[   73.814451] [eda15c20] [c0015a18] ret_from_except+0x0/0x1c    
[   73.815072] --- Exception: 901 at __do_softirq+0x8c/0x258    
[   73.815072]     LR = __do_softirq+0x24/0x258    
[   73.816154] [eda15d30] [c0046b48] irq_exit+0xa4/0xc8    
[   73.816640] [eda15d40] [c000c104] timer_interrupt+0x4c/0x64    
[   73.817274] [eda15d60] [c0015a18] ret_from_except+0x0/0x1c    
[   73.817812] --- Exception: 901 at uart_start+0x68/0x7c    
[   73.817812]     LR = uart_start+0x64/0x7c    
[   73.818668] [eda15e30] [c033a214] uart_write+0xc4/0x100    
[   73.819203] [eda15e60] [c031d9d8] n_tty_write+0x2d8/0x468    
[   73.819737] [eda15ec0] [c031a3dc] tty_write+0x158/0x274    
[   73.820272] [eda15ef0] [c01625b8] vfs_write+0xc4/0x200    
[   73.820824] [eda15f10] [c0162d70] SyS_write+0x58/0xd0    
[   73.821400] [eda15f40] [c00152e8] ret_from_syscall+0x0/0x40    
[   73.822105] --- Exception: c01 at 0xf8ba214    
[   73.822105]     LR = 0xf8ba1fc    
[   73.826882] handlers:    
[   73.827086] [<c0346e60>] pmz_interrupt    
[   73.827315] Disabling IRQ #17    
[   73.836018] [sched_delayed] sched: RT throttling activated    
AT[   77.590858] irq 16: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)    
[   77.592282] CPU: 0 PID: 395 Comm: ModemManager Not tainted 3.16.0-6-powerpc #1 Debian 3.16.56-1+deb8u1    
[   77.594339] Call Trace:    
[   77.594851] [efff5d70] [c000966c] show_stack+0xf8/0x1b0 (unreliable)    
[   77.596459] [efff5dc0] [c008ef3c] __report_bad_irq.isra.7+0x40/0xec    
[   77.598025] [efff5de0] [c008f304] note_interrupt+0x29c/0x2f4    
[   77.599321] [efff5e10] [c008cddc] handle_irq_event_percpu+0xe8/0x1dc    
[   77.602162] [efff5e50] [c008cf10] handle_irq_event+0x40/0x60    
[   77.602468] [efff5e60] [c008f908] handle_level_irq+0x9c/0x14c    
[   77.602796] [efff5e70] [c008c3a0] generic_handle_irq+0x48/0x68    
[   77.603326] [efff5e80] [c0006e08] __do_irq+0x44/0xf4    
[   77.603918] [efff5e90] [c0006f70] do_IRQ+0xb8/0xc0    
[   77.604396] [efff5eb0] [c000c0ec] timer_interrupt+0x34/0x64    
[   77.604975] [efff5ed0] [c0015a18] ret_from_except+0x0/0x1c    
[   77.605503] --- Exception: 901 at __do_softirq+0x8c/0x258    
[   77.605503]     LR = __do_softirq+0x24/0x258    
[   77.607725] [efff5fe0] [c0046b48] irq_exit+0xa4/0xc8    
[   77.608285] [efff5ff0] [c000f2fc] call_do_irq+0x24/0x3c    
[   77.608868] [eda15d40] [c0006f28] do_IRQ+0x70/0xc0    
[   77.609332] [eda15d60] [c0015a18] ret_from_except+0x0/0x1c    
[   77.609921] --- Exception: 501 at uart_start+0x68/0x7c    
[   77.609921]     LR = uart_start+0x64/0x7c    
[   77.610785] [eda15e30] [c033a214] uart_write+0xc4/0x100    
[   77.611293] [eda15e60] [c031d9d8] n_tty_write+0x2d8/0x468    
[   77.611848] [eda15ec0] [c031a3dc] tty_write+0x158/0x274    
[   77.612379] [eda15ef0] [c01625b8] vfs_write+0xc4/0x200    
[   77.612947] [eda15f10] [c0162d70] SyS_write+0x58/0xd0    
[   77.613449] [eda15f40] [c00152e8] ret_from_syscall+0x0/0x40    
[   77.614049] --- Exception: c01 at 0xf8ba214    
[   77.614049]     LR = 0xf8ba1fc    
[   77.614806] handlers:    
[   77.615059] [<c0346e60>] pmz_interrupt    
[   77.615471] Disabling IRQ #16
```

Comment: PowerPC is a tad esoteric these days. What machine are you on?

Comment: I have intel x86 machine with win10. Then I launch Ubuntu VM with Virtual Box. And on Ubuntu host I try to boot Debian for PowerPC32 with QEMU.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want a PowerPC build on an Intel.

Comment: I need to test some c++ code on different architectures, including PPC32, but don't have an actual machine, so I looked up for emulators and found out about QEMU and found this guide on how to install debian.

Answer (score 0):

I found ready to use PowerPC VMs. I used first answer to this question on SO and managed to launch Debian with QEMU.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971839/powerpc-emulation-qemu-pearpc-or

Comment: Please see the Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help). This answer is very likely to be flagged for content, as [link-only answers aren't considered good quality](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). There's no way to tell if the link target disappears, which would make this answer useless. Therefore you should expand your answer by adding the essential steps how exactly you resolved the issue. Leave the link here as a reference. [From Review](https://superuser.com/review/first-answers/1083442)